# Getting key/values using `for..of` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach, ecmascript-6

I was just playing around with `for...of` and tried to see how intuitive it was to get both the key and value of an entity being looped on and got to the following state:

```
for (var divEntries of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).entries()) {
    console.log(divEntries[0]); // Key
    console.log(divEntries[1]); // Value
}
```

Is there a better way to do this which would be a bit more semantic than using array positions on entries?

Comment: The entries of `querySelectorall` are iterable anyway. You don't need that `Array.from`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Not in all browsers that already support `for of` :-/

Comment: The question is about `for...of` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clearer way would be by using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
for (let [key, value] of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).entries() ) {
   console.log(key);
   console.log(value);
}
```

MDN has a list of examples about how  [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) can be used including the example with destructing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is more idiomatic to use destructuring in the loop header:

```
for (let [index, value] of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).entries()) {
    console.log(index); // Key
    console.log(value); // Value
}
```